# Finding the image of a matrix given two examples of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was given the following question:

> Let $e_1=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)$ and $e_2=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\\end{matrix}\right)$, $y_1=\left(\begin{matrix}3\\5\\\end{matrix}\right)$ and $y_2=\left(\begin{matrix}-1\\8\\\end{matrix}\right)$. Let $T:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be a linear transformation that maps $e_1$ to $y_1$ and $e_2$ to $y_2$. Find the image of $\left(\begin{matrix}4\\-3\\\end{matrix}\right)$.

It seems that I am supposed to find the matrix that results in the given transformations, and then apply that to the given vector. Is there a method to doing this? Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thought on how to approach it is correct. Every linear transformation is *uniquely determined* by its action on a basis. In this case, suppose the matrix of the transformation is $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)$. So you know
$$
 \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right) = \left
(\begin{array}{c} 3 \\ 5 \end{array}\right)
$$
Does that tell you anything about the matrix $A$?

Comment: I see! Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $Ae_1 = y_1$ and $Ae_2 = y_2$

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1\\
5 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the image of $
\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
-3
\end{bmatrix}
$
will be $ A \begin{bmatrix}
4\\
-3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
15\\
-4
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why A can just be the Y1 and the Y2?

Comment: Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c& d
\end{bmatrix}$ and think about how the matrix multiplication would work

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense now